# Numpy.load() error when using different platforms

Tags: python, numpy, save, load, platform

I'm using np.save/np.load to save my data into files and read from another script. Although the code is working properly under both windows and linux, there's a problem when i try to load my .npy files created in linux, with my windows setup. In both cases, i'm using python 3.6, with packages up to date (numpy version is same).

I noticed that this happens only in arrays with dtype=object, and not other type of arrays. The error I get is "TypeError: _reconstruct: First argument must be a sub-type of ndarray".

I tried to change allow_pickle parameter in np.save to False, but it didn't work (it wouldn't allow me to save several arrays).

Any idea what's wrong? Any suggestions on a different way to keep my data cross-platform?

Thanks

Edit: I tried some simple experiments with dictionaries and numpy arrays, and it turns out the problem exists in different configurations.

For example, pickle.dump() works for dictionaries if I export in Unix and load (pickle.load) on Windows, but not with numpy arrays.

On the other hand, np.save()/np.load() works for non-object numpy arrays, but not for dictionaries, when I export in Unix and load on Windows.

Both these methods fail for numpy objects or lists of arrays (e.g. list of np.arrays with different shapes)

Of course, np.save/np.load works properly for all kinds of data, given that the I use the same platform.

Any further ideas? I tried the hdf5 format, but I still get some errors.

Comment: With `object` dtype it pickles each object.

Comment: Are the classes from the same version of modules in both cases? Pickle doesn't like it when you create an object and change the class, or dynamically adding attributes to the object.